# rxjava 2.x hot observable within fragment

Tags: android, rx-java

I get a strange issue when unsubscribing and resubscribe a hot observable within a fragment, second subscribe won't receive any onNext. Here is my code :

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated( View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    getHotObservable().subscribe( new Observer<...>( )
            {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe( Disposable d )
                {
                    mCompositeDisposable.add( d );
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext( ... )
                {
                    ...
                }

                @Override
                public void onError( Throwable e )
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete( )
                {

                }
            } );
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView( )
{
    mCompositeDisposable.dispose( );
    super.onDestroyView( );
}
```

So with this implementation it works the first time fragment is created but if i replace my fragment and add transaction to backstack then poping backstack, i'll never get any onNext.

My actual workaround is to subscribe/unsubsribe from onAttach/onDetach and add a filter to my observable to check if fragment view is null

```
@Override
public void onAttach( Context context )
{
    super.onAttach( context );

    getHotObservable()
            .filter( new AppendOnlyLinkedArrayList.NonThrowingPredicate<...>( )
            {
                @Override
                public boolean test( ... )
                {
                    return getView( ) != null;
                }
            } )
            .subscribe( new Observer<...>( )
            {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe( Disposable d )
                {
                    mCompositeDisposable.add( d );
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext( ... )
                {
                    ...
                }

                @Override
                public void onError( Throwable e )
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete( )
                {

                }
            } );
}

@Override
public void onDetach( )
{
    mCompositeDisposable.dispose( );
    super.onDetach( );
}
```

I can't figure out why the first solution won't work since i'm subscribing with a fresh new observer each time. Maybe my workaround is the right way to go?

Thx!

Comment: What does your `onCreateView()` look like?

Comment: onCreateView only inflates fragment layout xml

Comment: What is your HotObservable?

Comment: my observable is a `PublishSubject` instantiate externally (does'nt belong to my fragment)

Comment: If i remove dispose from `onDestroyView`, i can navigate back and forth from this fragment and my observable is working but of course this lead to a leak.